# What does "be out in" mean?

Tags: songs

There's a song ["Winter"](https://genius.com/The-rolling-stones-winter-lyrics) by The Rolling Stones, and there's a line

> *And I wish I been out in California*

What does it mean - he wants to be in California or he's sad about being in California?

Comment: Out in California, out to the country, out to my grandparent's house.  Not here, but somewhere "out there".

Answer (score 8):

Here, *out* is used to express a location that’s at some fair distance away when used with the verb *be*. This is the same sense as when used with the verb *go*, as in this lyric from Neil Young:

> *Think I'll go out to Alberta,
>  weather's good there in the fall.
> I got some friends that
>  I could go to working for*

I am going to assume that your question stems from the fact that “I wish I been” is not grammatical in standard written English.  The second clause’s verb, *been*, is not in a finite tense as a subordinate clause would formally require, but rather is just the past participle alone without an auxiliary verb accompanying it.

Although this is a particularly casual, even rustic or unlettered, way of speaking, it does occur in native speakers. It represents an extremely laid back or careless way of speaking, something raw and unpolished. You can tell this by the rest of the lyrics, which has things in it like *draggin’* to mean *dragging* and the *’cross* to mean *across*, not to mention *ain’t*, a perfectly normal word in casual (or mock casual) speech but one frowned upon in standard English. There’s also a bit of mismatch between subject and verb in these lyrics.

So you have to know how casual English works, and you’ll have to fill in the blanks when things are left out.  Sometimes what’s missing may not be clear to non-native speakers first trying to learn English coming from another language, so you have to figure out what is possible and impossible to decide what was intended.

Normally, the subordinate clause following “I wish” would take one of two possibilities, depending on whether the counterfactual were in the future or in the past:

- I wish I were out in California.  (*in the future*)
- I wish I had been out in California. (*in the past*)

That makes the second possibility the one that was meant. However, the sense of the lyrics can in isolation be argued to require the meaning of the first possibility. But there’s a later, connected clause in the simple past, though, which makes *had been* the right choice to place it back before then.

A third possibility, *have been*, is one we must rule out because it is subordinate to the verb *wish*, which does not take a verb in the present tense. However, *has* is indeed the omitted verb in the first line of the song.

I’ve marked the non-standard bits below in bold.

> *And **it sure been** a cold, cold winter*
>   *And the wind **ain’t** been blowin’ from the south*
>   *It’s sure been a cold, cold winter*
>   *And a **lotta** love is all burned out*
>   
>   ***It sure been*** a hard, hard winter
>   *My **feet been draggin’ ’cross** the ground*
>   *And I hope it’s **gonna** be a long, hot summer*
>   *And a **lotta** love will be **burnin’** bright*
>   
>   *And I **wish I been** out in California*
>   *When the lights on all the Christmas trees went out*
>   *But **I been burnin’** my bell, book, and candle*
>   *And the restoration plays have all gone **’round***
>   
>   ***It sure been*** a cold, cold winter
>   *My **feet been draggin’ ’cross** the ground*
>   *And the **fields has** all been brown and fallow*
>   *And the **springtime take** a long way around*
>   
>   *Yeah, and I **wish I been** out in Stone Canyon*
>   *When the lights on all the Christmas trees went out*
>   *But **I been burnin’** my bell, book, and candle*
>   *And the restoration plays have all gone **’round***
>   
>   *Sometimes I think about you, baby*
>   *Sometimes I cry about you*
>   
>   *Sometimes I want to wrap my coat around you*
>   *Sometimes I want to keep you warm*
>   *Sometimes I want to wrap my coat around you*
>   *Sometimes I want to but I can’t afford you*

Comment: Very clear, detailed and exhaustive  answer,  OP will appreciate.

Comment: Great answer, but I think it lacks a conclusion. You've shown that it means "I wish I had been out in California". But, in turn, what does that mean? Even I am not sure. What does "To be out in California" mean? To be away from home, but in California? To be away from California? Or what? (Bonus: does the song imply that the person lives in California?) You've addressed the casual-english issue very well, but I feel that a conclusion is missing.

Comment: @Hamsteriffic It’s a song about winter, and winter affects much of California differently from the rest of the continent. Had he been in California for winter, it would not have been so cold.

Answer (score 5):

It could have several meanings, depending on when it was written, and what the context is: I don't know the song, so I can't say for sure which. But it is not your second option.

It could mean:

> in California, which is a long way from here
>
> in California, and going out not staying at home
>
> in California, and known to be gay.

I think it's probably the first one.

Comment: Definitely the first one: 'out' meaning 'far away'